# Java ASCII maze

Tags: java, matrix

I have a working ascii maze solver written in java, using a char array, where it sets each position of the correct path to the previous position + 1. I am using the following code to then get the correct path out of it, however it is only working on vertical movements. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
    int x, y;
    int max = Math.max((int)maze[maze.length-1][maze.length-2], 
                       (int)maze[maze.length-2][maze.length-1]);
    if(maze[maze.length-1][maze.length-2] == max)
    {
        x = maze.length-1;
        y = maze.length-2;
    }
    else
    {
        x = maze.length-2;
        y = maze.length-1;
    }
    for(int cur=0;cur<ans;cur++)
    {
        try
        {
            correct[x][y] = '*';
            if(maze[x-1][y] == maze[x][y]-1)
                x = x - 1;
            else if(maze[x+1][y] == maze[x][y]-1)
                x = x + 1;
            else if(maze[x][y-1] == maze[x][y]-1)
                y = y - 1;
            else if(maze[x][y+1] == maze[x][y]-1)
                y = y + 1;
        }catch(Throwable e){}
    }
```

Comment: First suggestion is get code like this: `catch(Throwable e){}` out of your program. Why on earth would you want to ignore exceptions like this? Crazy.

Comment: Next, if you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the catch was just for testing with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exceptions, do  you have a suggestion on how to do it without throwing them?

Comment: You never "catch" ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. That's as dangerous as trying to catch NullPointerExceptions. Yes, I suggest that you re-think your logic so that you test for end cases and create code that avoids ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

Comment: Thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels. I had never heard that it was dangerous to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, so I saw no other way to do it. I have solved it using a simple AND inside my if statements to check boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if it is frowned upon to answer your own question, but thanks to @HovercraftFullOfEels I've solved my own problem with the following modifications:

```
for(int cnt = 0; cnt < numSteps; cnt++)
{
    correct[x][y] = '*';
    if(x-1 >= 0 && maze[x-1][y] == maze[x][y]-1)
        x--;
    else if(x+1 < maze.length && maze[x+1][y] == maze[x][y]-1)
        x++;
    else if(y-1 >= 0 && maze[x][y-1] == maze[x][y]-1)
        y--;
    else if(y+1 < maze.length && maze[x][y+1] == maze[x][y]-1)
        y++;
}
```

Comment: I think answering your own question is considered good practice (when you can)

Comment: Indeed, and nice going. We may have a future programmer here.